# Model optimization using Minimize, Differential Evolution and Basinhopping

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, random-forest

I am working on a well known and simple Kaggle project for fun, but I am having some doubts when I see some of the predictions made by other contestants, they arrive to 100%.

There are two csv files, one called 'train.csv' and 'test.csv'; the first is to train, the second is to predict a binary feature. The binary feature to predict is called 'Survived', which is not present in the test csv file.

In order to pre-process the data, I loaded them as pandas dataframes. The test dataframe doesn't have the feature 'Survived', so I created a new column with the same name and a constant value of -1, to differentiate between the 0 and 1 of the corresponding column in the train dataframe. Then I've merged them row-wise.

I checked for duplicated rows and there weren't. I checked for missing values and I got

```
Feature     Missing_num     Missing_percent
Cabin       1014            77.463713
Age         263             20.091673
Embarked    2               0.152788
Fare        1               0.076394
```

I proceed to delete all those features with missing values larger than 30%. The features with missing percents smaller than 30% I imputed them using the library `DataWig`, which uses a LSTM algorithm.

For categorical features, I use the corresponding Label Encoder, to transform them to numerical.

Once the sample is clean, then I separate into train and test by selecting for training the data points such that 'Survived' !=-1.

To best predict the labels in the test subsample, I decided to optimize a Random Forest model, by minimizing the ratio MSE/AUC with respect to all the hyper-parameters, using different methods, like `Minimize`, `Differential Evolution` and `Basinhopping`, from `scipy.optimize`.

I train the model with the training subsample; I predict the labels of the training subsample, then I compute the MSE and the AUC, and the ratio MSE/AUC.

When I use `Minimize`, with the given initial conditions, it always finishes the process giving SUCCESS as response but it always gives the initial point.

When I use `Differential Evolution` and `Basinhopping`, I obtain a different result than the initial point from `Minimize`, however, I always get an AUC of 0.5, which says that the obtained model is giving random predictions.

[Here is the link to the project.](https://github.com/elopezfune/Kaggle_Titanic/find/main)

I would like to know what am I doing wrong and why the model is giving random predictions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at `Y_pred` and see what the predicted values look like that give you AUC 0.50. I see you are using `predict` instead of `predict_proba` so your model will perform badly on MSE and AUC.